# Decorating arithmetic operators | should I be using a metaclass?

Tags: python, metaclass

I'd like to implement an object, that bounds values within a given range after arithmetic operations have been applied to it. The code below works fine, but I'm pointlessly rewriting the methods. Surely there's a more elegant way of doing this. Is a metaclass the way to go?

```
def check_range(_operator):
    def decorator1(instance,_val):
        value =  _operator(instance,_val)
        if value > instance._upperbound:
            value = instance._upperbound
        if value < instance._lowerbound:
            value = instance._lowerbound
        instance.value = value
        return Range(value, instance._lowerbound, instance._upperbound)
    return decorator1

class Range(object):
    '''
    however you add, multiply or divide, it will always stay within boundaries
    '''
    def __init__(self, value, lowerbound, upperbound):
        '''

        @param lowerbound:
        @param upperbound:
        '''
        self._lowerbound = lowerbound
        self._upperbound = upperbound
        self.value = value

    def init(self):
        '''
        set a random value within bounds
        '''
        self.value = random.uniform(self._lowerbound, self._upperbound)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Range: %s>" % (self.value)

    @check_range
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.value * other

    @check_range
    def __div__(self, other):
        return self.value / float(other)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self.div(other)     

    @check_range
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.value + other

    @check_range
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.value - other
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use a metaclass to apply a decorator to a set of function names, but I don't think that this is the way to go in your case. Applying the decorator in the class body on a function-by-function basis as you've done, with the `@decorator` syntax, I think is a very good option.  (I think you've got a bug in your decorator, BTW: you probably do not want to set `instance.value` to anything; arithmetic operators usually don't mutate their operands).

Another approach I might use in your situation, kind of avoiding decorators all together, is to do something like this:

```
import operator

class Range(object):

    def __init__(self, value, lowerbound, upperbound):
        self._lowerbound = lowerbound
        self._upperbound = upperbound
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Range: %s>" % (self.value)

    def _from_value(self, val):
        val = max(min(val, self._upperbound), self._lowerbound)
        # NOTE: it's nice to use type(self) instead of writing the class
        # name explicitly; it then continues to work if you change the
        # class name, or use a subclass
        return type(self)(val, rng._lowerbound, rng._upperbound)

    def _make_binary_method(fn):
        # this is NOT a method, just a helper function that is used
        # while the class body is being evaluated
        def bin_op(self, other):
            return self._from_value(fn(self.value, other))
        return bin_op

    __mul__ = _make_binary_method(operator.mul)
    __div__ = _make_binary_method(operator.truediv)
    __truediv__ = __div__
    __add__ = _make_binary_method(operator.add)
    __sub__ = _make_binary_method(operator.sub)

rng = Range(7, 0, 10)
print rng + 5
print rng * 50
print rng - 10
print rng / 100
```

printing

```
<Range: 10>
<Range: 10>
<Range: 0>
<Range: 0.07>
```

I suggest that you do NOT use a metaclass in this circumstance, but here is one way you could. Metaclasses are a useful tool, and if you're interested, it's nice to understand how to use them for when you really need them.

```
def check_range(fn):
    def wrapper(self, other):
        value = fn(self, other)
        value = max(min(value, self._upperbound), self._lowerbound)
        return type(self)(value, self._lowerbound, self._upperbound)
    return wrapper

class ApplyDecoratorsType(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        for decorator, names in attrs.get('_auto_decorate', ()):
            for name in names:
                fn = attrs.get(name, None)
                if fn is not None:
                    setattr(cls, name, decorator(fn))

class Range(object):
    __metaclass__ = ApplyDecoratorsType
    _auto_decorate = (
            (check_range, 
             '__mul__ __div__ __truediv__ __add__ __sub__'.split()),
        )

    def __init__(self, value, lowerbound, upperbound):
        self._lowerbound = lowerbound
        self._upperbound = upperbound
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Range: %s>" % (self.value)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.value * other

    def __div__(self, other):
        return self.value / float(other)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self / other

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.value + other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.value - other
```

Comment: I think this most clearly answers the OPs question, but I think the other answer has a slightly better solution to the problem.

Comment: Wow, many thanks Matt. I agree that the solution where you neither use decorators nor metaclasses is the cleanest. Thanks a lot for showing me the type(self) idea and how to apply decorators automagically. Highly instructive, thanks a lot!

Comment: A question on the interesting type(self) pattern:
class RRRange(Range):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Range.__init__(self, *args)
    
    def whatsmytype(self):
        return type( self )

rng = RRRange(7, 0, 10)
print rng + 5 # returns a Range nor RRRange object

How is type(self)(val, rng._lowerbound, rng._upperbound) different from 
Range(self)(val, rng._lowerbound, rng._upperbound)?
Come to think of it, the metaclass approach would have made more sense if it would not be necessary to have to redefine the arithmetic operator. I'm curious whether that is doable?

Comment: It does return an `RRRange` object. Change your `__repr__()` method body to `return "<%s(%r)>" % (type(self).__name__, self.value)` instead to more easily see. Even better, change it to `return "%s(%r, %r, %r)" % (type(self).__name__, self.value, self._lowerbound, self._upperbound)`.

Answer (score 1):

As it is wisely said about metaclasses: ***if you wonder wether you need them, then you don't***.

I don't fully understand your problem, but I would create a `BoundedValue` class, and us only instances of said class into the class you are proposing.

```
 class BoundedValue(object):
    default_lower = 0
    default_upper = 1
    def __init__(self, upper=None, lower=None):
        self.upper = upper or BoundedValue.default_upper
        self.lower = lower or BoundedValue.default_lower
    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val
    @val.setter
    def val(self, value):
        assert self.lower <= value <= self.upper
        self._val = value


v = BoundedValue()
v.val = 0.5 # Correctly assigns the value 0.5
print v.val # prints 0.5
v.val = 10  # Throws assertion error
```

Of course you could (and should) change the `assert`ion for the actual behavior you are looking for; also you can change the constructor to include the initialization value. I chose to make it an assignment post-construction via the property `val`.

Once you have this object, you can create your classes and use BoundedValue instances, instead of `float`s or `int`s.

Comment: Using a property is probably might be a good idea.
However, what I'm really curious of is how I can apply the decorator to the arithmetic operators? I suppose I'm looking for a pattern more something amongst these lines:

class Range(object)
    self.__new__( self ):
       for i in [self.__mul__, self.__add__, ...]:
           i = check_range(i)